# How to pass variables into an escaped json string?

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to pass json into a REST api call in order to start builds on VSTS.

The body has two parameters that are passed in as an escaped string and i'm struggling to update the parameters before invoking my request. An example of my body is below:

```
$body ='
{
    "definition":
    {
        "id": ""
    },
    "parameters": "{\"environment\":\"uat\", \"browser\":  \"ie\"}"
}
'
```

This is passed into the following where I update the definition id successfully:

```
$bodyJson=$body | ConvertFrom-Json
$bodyjson.definition.id = $buildDefId
$bodyString=$bodyJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

This works successfully but I can't access the parameters element of the json in order to pass the browser and environments in as variables.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

I have tried the following without success:

```
$params = $bodyJson.Paramaters
$params -replace "uat","test"
$bodyString=$bodyJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

This updates the parameter in `$params` but it isn't passed back into the json when converted. I feel that i'm close but obviously missing a step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you have a Json (`parameters`) string embedded in another Json string.
Meaning that you have to `ConvertFrom-Json` twice to deserialize everything and `ConvertTo-Json` twice to serialize it back with the new parameters:
<sub>(Note that I swapped the variable names `$body` and `$bodyJson` because `$body` is an object and `$bodyJson` is actually your Json string)</sub>

```
$bodyJson = '
{
    "definition": {
        "id": ""
    },
    "parameters": "{\"environment\":\"uat\", \"browser\":  \"ie\"}"
}
'
$body = $bodyJson | ConvertFrom - Json
$paramJson = $body.parameters
$parameters = $paramJson | ConvertFrom - Json
$parameters

environment browser
----------- -------
uat         ie
```

Change the parameter:

```
$parameters.environment = "test"
```

And rebuild the Json string:

```
$paramJson = $parameters | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
$body.parameters = $paramJson
$bodyJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json
$bodyJson
{
    "definition":  {
                       "id":  ""
                   },
    "parameters":  "{\"environment\":\"test\",\"browser\":\"ie\"}"
}
```

Comment: Wow - was not expecting that! Worked perfectly though, thank you.